# adding a counter to a column in sharepoint website without using designer

Tags: sharepoint, counter

how can i add a counter to sharepoint column, just like in this image? I am not allowed to use sharepoint designer for this purpose. I have done this before but I am not sure how I got to that page
[image]

Answer (score 0):

click on the three dots above the column names and click on 'Modify View' then scroll down to the 'Totals' tab at the bottom and click on the plus sign. Go to the column you want to show the counter for and select 'Sum' or 'Count' depending on your requirement.
Click 'Ok'